# Heroku Procfile for SpringMVC application

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, heroku

Im trying to deploy my simple SpringMVC application to heroku. I've almost done it but at the last moment after command

```
git push heroku master
```

it came message

```
push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
```

I've read already that I need some file Procfile in the root of project.

The problems are:
1) What to write in that Procfile?
2) Locally Im using Tomcat web server but in all examples I've found in the internet people say that they were using Jetty.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because Heroku can't determine which buildpack to use.

Is your Spring server at the root of your repository? Heroku searches only at the root to find the necessary files to pick which buildpack to use.

I had the same problem, and I fixed it by moving my Spring app to the root. Heroku does all the behind the scenes work.